# Can restful POST api send back two different resources in the API response based on request body parameter?

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture

We have a website to connect buyer and seller of goods.

We are designing POST API to capture interest of buyers on any seller product. The API Uri and request body looks like:

```
/api/lead/
{
   "name":"xyz",
   "mobile": "00984343",
   "stockid":4
}
```

The API is POST since we will save this information in database.

Currently, if "stockid" is stock belonging to our premium customer, the API sends back seller details in API response body:

```
{
  "sellername":"abc",
  "sellermobile":"75654647",
  "selleraddress": "faje street, curl"
}
```

If "stockid" is stock belonging to our normal customer, the API sends back complete details of that product in API response body (and DO NOT send back seller details)

```
{
  "description": "good 2nd hand mobile",
  "purchasedate": "24 july,2017",
  "purchaseprice": "10000"
}
```

The same POST API is sending back 2 different types of resources (one is seller details, other is stock details) based on the stock id.

Is it restful to design API this way i.e. POST API sending back multiple types of responses based on some request body parameter?

Answer (score 1):

This practice looks questionable. Personally I would not do that.

Suggestion 1: return details of product for normal customer, and details of product **plus** seller details for premium one, as form of enrichment of response. With that both responses are mostly consistent and you still have functionality you want.

EDIT: added more suggestions I thought of.

Suggestion 2: since those responses are basically different, maybe they should be returned by different resources. In that case, don't return data during POST, just use id to make calls to something like `api/seller/{stockid}` and `api/product/{stockid}` which would return responses or `No content` if id is invalid for specific resource. Downside, you need to make many calls and it complicates architecture.

Suggestion 3: To avoid totally different response objects, which is confusing and makes harder for the client to map them, use some wrapper object that provides some "type" property and your object inside. Something like :

```
{
  "type" : "premium",
  "data" : {
     "sellername":"abc",
     "sellermobile":"75654647",
     "selleraddress": "faje street, curl"
  }
}
```

Not perfect, but in my opinion better than two totally different responses.

Comment: "POST should be used for creating objects" - please provide a reference for this.

Comment: Not sure what would count as objective reference, but resources are pretty consistent on this [example1](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html) [example2](http://restcookbook.com/HTTP%20Methods/put-vs-post/)

Comment: From your first reference, second sentence: " It's quite possible, valid and even preferred in some occasions, to use PUT to create resources, or use POST to update resources." From your second reference, under "PUT": "However, PUT can also be used to create a resource in the case where the resource ID is chosen by the client instead of by the server."

Comment: Not sure what is your point now. You are referring to POST vs PUT distinction now? Well, that's another story I would say. In my (simplified) answer to sahil I wanted to point that using POST for getting data is probably not RESTful and GET would be preferable. Another thing, considering there is no actual RESTful "standard", there is no objective reference to anything and each source we rely on is some kind of interpretation. So I fully accept there might be some inconsistencies and want just to show general direction.

Comment: The point is that POST is not "create". It is reasonable in some cases to return query data from a POST request. It may or may not be a good idea in this case, but it's not always wrong. Also, REST doesn't say anything about how to use POST - that's found in the HTTP spec. There is a REST definition: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm. There is an HTTP standard: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231 (7230-7235). "RESTful" has no agreed-upon meaning.

Comment: It is always sometimes reasonable to do something else in specific situation.Some common sense is important.And I know the difference between non-standard RESTful vs REST vs HTTP.But then,should we always go down to the bottom of the rabbit hole of details or just give some reasonable rules of thumb and let people figure more when they needed? If someone wanted spec level details, they would google that not ask SO. Most people I know doing REST had put in the head POST=create at the beginning by someone older, and they live happily doing not so bad designs,until they feel need to learn more

Comment: editted the question. It is POST because we are saving this lead in database. But why would we send back "details of product plus seller details for premium one", as we only need  "seller details " in that case

Comment: Ok, then my second remark was clear miss. Now, about your question (this here is my opinion rather than any standard) : Firstly consistent responses are less confusing for the client(s). Secondly, mapping, with such dual response client cannot just map response to single object, he needs to do some if else logic, or have knowledge whether his id was premium or not

Comment: @JamesCube: so what should be done in such cases? make duplicate APIs or what?

Comment: @sahil Extended my answer, hope this helps you

Comment: @JamesCube: I like the 3rd suggestion. But is it restful? do we have any reference if rest permits API to send back different type of response i.e. having different fields inside "data" JSON object based on "type" clients get back in response?

Comment: @sahil This question is practically impossible to answer since, like also Erik Stein pointed here before, what is "restful" is not clearly defined. I never encounter resources that deal with such details of responses, so cannot say either. The best answer I can offer you is "I think that suggestion 3 is better than what you are trying to do right now". But that is only opinion from my experience doing REST.